# How to generate sequential incremental id to DatabaseGeneratedOption Identity in entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, ef-code-first

We are using entity framework code first model and its class structure is as below

```
 public class BaseSchema
{
    [Key]
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Is Deleted")]
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
}

public class School : BaseSchema
{
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(20)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

When we save the information in school table it's Id field is not generating in sequence. Ex initially it started with 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 in sequence and then suddenly it created next id value as 1011, 2011
We are saving in school as below

```
using (var context = new DataContext())
{
    School newschool = new School { Name = "UniqueSchoolName" };
    context.School.Add(newschool);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Can you please guide why it's not generating ids in sequence?
Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

you should not care about gaps.

It's by design, for performance reason SQL Server caches 1,000 numbers and on SQL Server restart the cache is gone.

And the behavior is well documented see [CREATE TABLE (Transact-SQL) IDENTITY (Property)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql-identity-property?view=sql-server-ver15) => Remarks: "Consecutive values after server restart or other failures "

Also, When inserts are rolled back, the identity values are NOT reset

Comment: Understood, but how about dealing with large data, if any primary key exceeds int range, we need to make to long. How to fill this gaps?

Comment: int has limitation if you have large data sets.If it reaches its limit, Insert failed . you should use either BigInt or Unique Identifier -  GUID.